# Float: right is messing up the order

Tags: javascript, css, alignment

In the project im making, I want users to be able to upload images. Those images **MUST** be ordered from first uploaded to last uploaded.

Take a look at the following code:

```css
body{
color:white;
}

#wrap{
margin-top:10px;
overflow:hidden;
}

#container{
background:#121212;
max-width:250px;
padding:5px;
overflow:hidden;
float:right;
padding:5px 5px 0 0;
}

.img_c{
height:50px;
overflow:hidden;
float:right;
margin:0 0 5px 5px;
}

.img_c img{
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
}

.l{
float:left; /*When I use this, images are displayed in the correct order*/
}

.r{
float:right; /*Wierd behavior!!*/
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<div id="container">

<p>Float:left</p>

<div class="img_c l">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/3NgXgXkD/0001.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c l">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/h4x1WB2P/0002.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c l">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/FRkgK5mp/0003.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c l">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/kGrN61gm/0004.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c l">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/VvcMLJKs/0005.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c l">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/FzgSfh6y/0006.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c l">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/MTBVS7br/0007.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c l">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/WpMgY74d/0008.jpg">
</div>

</div></div>

<div id="wrap">
<div id="container">

<p>Float:right</p>

<div class="img_c r">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/3NgXgXkD/0001.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c r">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/h4x1WB2P/0002.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c r">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/FRkgK5mp/0003.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c r">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/kGrN61gm/0004.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c r">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/VvcMLJKs/0005.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c r">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/FzgSfh6y/0006.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c r">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/MTBVS7br/0007.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c r">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/WpMgY74d/0008.jpg">
</div>

</div>
```

As you can see, when I float the contents of `#container` to the left, everything is ordered that way:

```
[img0001] [img0002] [img0003] [img0004]
[img0005] [img0006] [img0007]
[img0008]
```

Which order my images in the correct way. Yay!

But when I use `float:right`, every **row** of images is inverted, which means  I can't just reverse the list of images in the DOM.. Basically, it gives us the following result:

```
[img0004] [img0003] [img0002] [img0001]
          [img0007] [img0006] [img0005]
                              [img0008]
```

This is what I expected:

```
[img0001] [img0002] [img0003] [img0004]
          [img0005] [img0006] [img0007]
                              [img0008]
```

How can I resolve this issue?

*Side note: Someone just suggested Javascript had nothing to do with the question. The thing is, if theres no CSS-only solution, I won't bother using a Javascript solution.*

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to float only the parent (container) not the child elements.

Comment: If I float the parent, the images wont be aligned? The goal here is to align the images to the right inside the `#container` @AlonsoCT

Comment: `float:right` does not mean *align* to the right, perhaps you should read a bit of background on how float works  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Comment: Ok, I understand, You already tried using flexbox?
https://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/
https://flexbox.help/

Comment: @AlonsoCT I'd prefer not to because my audience has old browsers (Opera Mini being the most used)

Comment: @AlonsoCT also it appears that flexbox needs to know how many images must there be. In this case, that value is unknown.

Comment: @skyline3000 I took a look at your link, but I didn't saw anything concerning re-ordering. `float:inline-start` sounded promising, tho it doesnt works.

Comment: "As mentioned above, when an element is floated, it is taken out of the normal flow of the document (though still remaining part of it). It is shifted to the left, or right, until it touches the edge of its containing box, or another floated element." So when you float multiple sequential elements to the right, the first one shifts all the way right to the container element's edge, the second will shift right all the way until touching the first element, the third element will shift all the way right until it's next to the second element, and so on, thus the order is "reversed" visually.

Comment: @skyline3000 so basically, I shouldn't be using floats for this task. What should I use instead? Flexbox is too new-ish for my audience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid the "order mess" instead of `float: right` use the combination of `display: inline-block` and `text-align: right`.

I also changed your duplicated IDs to class names.

```css
body{
color:white;
}

.wrap{
margin-top:10px;
overflow:hidden;
}

.container{
float:right;
background:#121212;
max-width:250px;
padding:5px;
overflow:hidden;
padding:5px 5px 0 0;
}

.img_c{
height:50px;
overflow:hidden;
margin:0 0 5px 5px;
display: inline-block; /* here's the trick */
}

.img_c img{
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
}

.cl{
text-align:left;
}

.cr{
text-align:right; /*no more weird behavior!!*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap cl">
<div class="container">

<p>Float:left</p>

<div class="img_c l">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/3NgXgXkD/0001.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c l">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/h4x1WB2P/0002.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c l">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/FRkgK5mp/0003.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c l">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/kGrN61gm/0004.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c l">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/VvcMLJKs/0005.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c l">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/FzgSfh6y/0006.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c l">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/MTBVS7br/0007.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c l">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/WpMgY74d/0008.jpg">
</div>

</div></div>

<div class="wrap cr">
<div class="container">

<p>Float:right</p>

<div class="img_c r">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/3NgXgXkD/0001.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c r">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/h4x1WB2P/0002.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c r">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/FRkgK5mp/0003.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c r">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/kGrN61gm/0004.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c r">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/VvcMLJKs/0005.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c r">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/FzgSfh6y/0006.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c r">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/MTBVS7br/0007.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img_c r">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/WpMgY74d/0008.jpg">
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Theres a misunderstanding here.. I want the **images** to be aligned to the right, without messing up the order.

Comment: Is my question unclear? I can change it if you want.

Comment: Fixed, plz forgive me for the misunderstood. Tell me if you need any further changes

Comment: Found the answer by myself here as well, tho I must thank you for helping me so much. Here, take this "accept answer" thingy!